# Why doesn't my seperator parameter work ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, printing, parameters

I am trying to print i value in one line. I used end but the code grade didn't accept it so I tried sep but it seems not working.

start=int(input("Give starting value: "))
stop=int(input("Give stopping value: "))

print("\nStarting for loop:")

for i in range(start,stop+1):
print(i,sep = " ")

print("\n\nThank you for using the program.")

Answer (score 0):

`sep` is to separate values in the same call to `print`. You probably actually want to use the end parameter: `print(i, end= " ")`

Answer (score 0):

The `sep` keyword is for separating multiple values.  the `end` keyword argument is meant for using to end the line with something other than the default line break.

to demonstrate

```
>>>
>>> for i in range(12):
...     print(i, end=' - ')
...
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 
>>>
>>> print(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, sep=" - ")
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11
>>>
```

As you can see the `sep` only works when you have multiple values being printed in the same print statement...